# What is the Krull dimension of a polynomial ring over a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

Recently, I proved this statement:

**Proposition:** Let $R$ be a PID. The prime ideals of $R[y]$ are precisely the ideals of the following form:

1. $(0)$,
2. $(f(y))$ where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $R[Y]$
3. $(p, f(y))$ where $p \in R$ is prime and $f(y)$ is irreducible in $R[y]$ and its image is irreducible in $(R/p)[y]$.

Note: Maximal ideals are of the third form and vice versa.

Using this statement I would like to show that the Krull dimension of $k[x,y]$ is 2 where $k$ is a field. However, I'm stuck at showing that there can't be a chain of prime ideals of the form $\{0\}\subsetneq (f)\subsetneq (p,g)$ i.e a chain involving every ideal of the types shown above.

Any ideas? In the case when R is a general PID would the Krull dimension be 2 or 3?

Comment: These sorts of chains can certainly exist when $R$ is a PID! For example, $(0) \subset (2) \subset (2,x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. Geometrically, a PID can be either $0$-dimensional (if it is a field) or $1$-dimensional (otherwise), and adjoining a polynomial indeterminate increases the dimension by $1$. So $R[x,y]$ might have dimension $2$ or $3$ in general, and here you need to use the fact that $k$ is a field.

Comment: More to the point, chains of the form $(0) \subset (f) \subset (p,g)$ tell you that the Krull dimension is at least 2, not at least 3! For example, $k[x,y]$ (which has dimension $2$) contains the chain $(0) \subset (x) \subset (x,y)$. You need to show that there do not exist any chains of the form $0 \subset p_1 \subset p_2 \subset p_3$.

Comment: Oh right sorry my mistake I mistook the length as the length as the number of prime ideals and not the "links"

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make! I try to remember that fields have dimension $0$ and a unique prime ideal, so in general the dimension ought to be one less than the number of prime ideals in a maximal chain.

Comment: @JhonDoe You have everything in front of you, and there is no need to invoke general results on Krull dimension of polynomial rings in order to conclude that $\dim R[y]=2$. The ideals of height one are principal, that is, those from 2. The maximal ideals from 3. have height two since $(0)\subsetneq (p)\subsetneq(p,f(y))$ is a maximal chain: if $P$ is a prime containing $p$ and contained in $(p,f(y))$, then $P/(p)$ is a prime in $R/(p)[y]$, so it is generated by a polynomial which is irreducible modulo $p$, and this is necessarily $f(y)$.

Comment: @user26857 i think you also need to argue why there cannot be any other prime ideal between $(0)$ and $(p,f(y))$ (Kaplanski's Lemma gives you that there has to be a principal prime ideal, but I'm not sure why it has to be generated by $p$, or am I missing something?)

Comment: It doesn't matter which primes are in between. We are trying here to find out the maximum length of a chain of prime ideals between $(0)$ and $(p,f(y))$, and the right question is if there are *two* primes $P\subsetneq Q$. Are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every PID which is not a field has Krull dimension $1$. Also, every PID is Noetherian, and if $R$ is Noetherian whose Krull dimension is $n$, then $R[x]$ has Krull dimension $n+1$. Therefore the answer to your question is that that Krull dimension of $R[y]$ is $2$.

Comment: This requires that the definition of PID excludes fields (which have dimension $0$, but also the property that all of their ideals are principal)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk right, corrected.