# $R[x]$ has Krull dimension 2 if $R$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

As mentioned before on this platform, I am self-studying some commutative algebra out of *A Course in Commutative Algebra* by Kemper. I am trying to attempt the following problem from the text.

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain which is not a field. Show that the polynomial ring $R[x]$ has (Krull) dimension 2.

My attempt at this exercise is to show that $\dim(R[x]) \geq 2$ and $\dim(R[x]) \leq 2.$ I have been able to show the first claim, namely:

We know that $R$ has at least one prime element $p \in R$, giving rise to a chain
$${0} \subset (x)_{R[x}] \subset (x, p)_{R[x]}$$
of prime ideals. So $\dim(R[x]) \geq 2.$

Its showing that $\dim(R[x]) \leq 2$ that is giving me problems. Now, I am aware that for a Noetherian ring $R \neq \{ 0 \}$ we have
$$\dim (R[x]) = \dim(R) + 1.$$
This fact would prove the exercise, however this fact is not introduced until later in the text so I want  to prove this exercise without it.
Any help one showing why $\dim(R[x]) \leq 2$ would be appreciated!

Comment: In a comment under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046287) I have made clear how to prove what you want without any reference to the general result about the dimension of polynomial rings.

Comment: I see! thank you! I was thinking about looking at $\text{Quot}(R)$.